# Apache Shiro, isPermitted() isn´t working

Tags: permissions, shiro

I'm making some testing with Apache Shiro just for learn, and i have a problem with permissions. The method isPermitted() just not work I mean, it's always return false.

shiro.ini

```
[main]

sha256Matcher = org.apache.shiro.authc.credential.HashedCredentialsMatcher
sha256Matcher.hashAlgorithmName=SHA-256


authc.loginUrl = /faces/views/login.xhtml
authc.successUrl = /faces/views/index.xhtml

builtInCacheManager = org.apache.shiro.cache.MemoryConstrainedCacheManager
securityManager.cacheManager = $builtInCacheManager

jdbcRealm=org.apache.shiro.realm.jdbc.JdbcRealm
jdbcRealm.permissionsLookupEnabled = true 
jdbcRealm.authenticationQuery = select senha from VUsuarioPerfil where usuario = ?
jdbcRealm.userRolesQuery = select perfil from VUsuarioPerfil where usuario = ?
jdbcRealm.permissionsQuery = select permissoes from VUsuarioPerfil where usuario = ?

jdbcRealm.credentialsMatcher = $sha256Matcher

ds = com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnectionPoolDataSource
ds.serverName = 192.168.50.254
ds.user = xx
ds.password = xxx
ds.databaseName = shiro
jdbcRealm.dataSource = $ds
```

Each user should have his own permission, so on the view(VUsuarioPerfil) there is a column called permissoes where I placed a string, like "clientes:visualizar".
And on code I test this way

```
public void test() {
    System.out.println(SecurityUtils.getSubject().hasRole("usuario"));
    System.out.println(SecurityUtils.getSubject().isPermitted("clientes:visualizar"));
}
```

Result is output:

```
true
false
```

I don't now why just the permission isn't caught on database.

Answer (score 4):

In the JDBC realm, the permissions query is not expected to map users->roles, it is expected to map roles->permissions.

So essentially, the query that is getting called is:

```
select permissoes from VUsuarioPerfil where usuario = usuario
```

And, as you would expect, it returns nothing.  Therefore the role has no permissions, and the user has no permissions.

Perhaps considering the default permissions query would help you think about how to map a query to your data structure?

```
select permission from roles_permissions where role_name = ?
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out your property:

```
select permissoes from VUsuarioPerfil
```

You need to correct **permissions**

Comment: Ok, nevermind you can keep whatever field names you prefer in your table